# JsonSerializationException how to solve

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net, jsonconvert

I have been trying deserialiable the api and the program shows this error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Diagnostics.Activity]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'activity', line 1, position 12.'

This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmsPz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoXUj.png)

thanks if someone can help me

Comment: Please include the code (ideally as a [mcve]) *and JSON* as text rather than images.

Comment: Are you really trying to transport/serialize a System.Diagnostics.Activity? Thats something that feels problematic to serialize. It not just public data and its an IDisposable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code, errors and JSON as **text** rather than as screenshots. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**if your json data looks like this :**

```
     jsonData = [{"id":"518523721","name":"ftyft"},

              {"id":"527032438","name":"ftyftyf"},

              {"id":"527572047","name":"ftgft"},

              {"id":"531141884","name":"ftftft"}]
```

**then you can try :**

```
    public class Person
     
    {
     
         public string Id { get; set; }
    
         public string Name { get; set; }
     
    }
    
     
    var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

**in case of array format :**

```
    public class PersonArray
     
    {          

        public Pserson[] Person{get;set;}
     
    }

  var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonArray>(json);
```